# What are some algorithms with runtimes that involve a \log{n} term with a negative exponent?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Are there any (deterministic or randomized) algorithms that run in time $\operatorname{poly}(n)\log^p{n}$ for $p < 0$? What are some examples?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following algorithm:

```
Input: a natural number n
Output: the list of prime numbers ≤ n

lst ← []
for x from 2 to n do
    if x is not a multiple of any number in lst then
       append x to lst
return lst
```

Using the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), it is not that difficult to prove that the algorithm runs in $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{n^2}{\log n}\right)$.

Of course, this algorithm is quite inefficient, as the [sieve of Erathosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) runs in $\mathcal{O}(n\log \log n)$ (and some versions of it in $\mathcal{O}(n)$), but it is simple to implement, so it is an example as good as it is.

Comment: I see, interesting, thanks. I wonder what else is out there.